# Kendoui grid overlaps

Tags: kendo-grid

I am using kendoui grid , which is shown when I click in a bubbletree(its like tree structure). The data in the grid comes dynamically on clicking bubbletree . The kendoui grid loads fine on first click but the grid overlaps on second click and so on gets overlapping .
I am using following code.

```
function showKendouiGrid(nodeCoordinate) {
        var kendouiConstants = {
            BASE_URL: 'http://',
            DATA_URL: '/eventbot/public/bubbletreedata/list-category?category=' + nodeCoordinate.label,
            PAGE_SIZE: 20,
            GRID_HEIGHT: 100
        }
        jQuery("#grid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [{
                field: 'label',
                title: "Activitiy",
            }],
            dataSource: {
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: kendouiConstants.PAGE_SIZE,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: kendouiConstants.BASE_URL + window.location.host + kendouiConstants.DATA_URL,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "GET"
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "data",
                    total: "total"
                },
                serverFiltering: true,
            },
            height: kendouiConstants.GRID_HEIGHT,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true
            },
            selectable: "row",
            scrollable: true,
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
        });
    }
```

There is another issue also that , the footer of kendoui grid shows "no items to display" , while it has items on it .
[image: this is the image of my work]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you click on the bubble tree, the grid is regenerated on the previous version of the grid. So, the first time you do it, all is fine and you end up with newly generated kendogrid markup which has its own wrapper elements in HTML. Next time you create the grid, it is recreated on the older and the wrappers are 'rewrapped' inside the previous ones.

What you should do is either .destroy() the grid or just change the grid datasource when the tree is clicked.